# How long can one be held in custody following arrest for s12 Terrorism offences?

Tags: england-and-wales, arrest, terrorism, custody, habeas-corpus

3 individuals were reportedly arrested on the afternoon of 13/01 on suspicion of supporting a proscribed organisation (namely Hamas) contrary to section 12 Terrorism Act 2000 and are still not released from police custody.

The normal limit for custody is 24 hours, but I’ve heard that the Terrorism Act contains certain provisions for extended custody periods. What then is the limit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the detention without charge time limits?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84022/what-are-the-detention-without-charge-time-limits)

Answer (score 6):

### [28 days](https://justice.org.uk/pre-charge-detention-terrorism-cases/)

The maximum period of pre-charge detention is 28 days. Also, the maximum in other cases is 72 hours, not 24.

Comment: Maximum is 14 days since Protection of Freedoms Act 2012. https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2012/9/part/4/crossheading/precharge-detention-of-terrorist-suspects/enacted

Comment: @Lag that amendment didn't entirely eliminate detention beyond 14 days, but requires the Secretary of State to invoke emergency powers in order to extend it to 28.